# How to fire Netbeans j2ee project in openshift (hello word!!)

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, netbeans-7, openshift

i have j2ee project on netbeans7.2, i copy .war file in apache tomcat 7 (web app folder) and it deploy, and work good,

how to deply and fire a simple netbeans j2ee project(like hello word) in open shift???

i do some instruction but can not complete it,

please leave answer step by step,

thanks

Comment: It is so user un-firendly and there is some problems and bugs, But with  compilation of git and ruby and putty and netbeans openshift plugin I do Robenrajan suggestion and it is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest

1. Create a new application in OpenShift
2. Install rhc client tools https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-client-tools.html
3. Download the project using GIT Open the project in netbeans as Maven Project
4. Now you can run the project in you local environment also.
5. You can deploy the code to openshift from netbeans via Git push.

Comment: For installing client tools - https://www.openshift.com/videos/installing-the-new-and-improved-openshift-client-tools-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a Java EE application on OpenShift, then you need to use an application server that can handle Java EE, such as JBoss AS 7, JBoss EAP, or WildFly.  Try creating a gear with one of those cartridges then your application should work.  If it does not, try giving us some information from the error logs about why it is not working, or what you tried that did not work.